# Cell based NSTableView(NSOutlineView)'s selection is not filled up with selection color in 10.14 Mojave beta

Tags: nstableview, nsoutlineview, macos-mojave

I have a macOS App build which has a NSOutlineView. It's cell based.

Build in Xcode 10 beta and run in 10.13 High Sierra, the selection is fine.
Build in Xcode 10 beta and run in 10.14 Mojave, the selection is not stable.

I run PXSourceList Example and results are the same.

In this picture, first I select 'AudioBooks', then I select 'Movies'. But 'Movies' is not filled up with selection background color.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same thing with view-based NSOutlineview in Majove. Seems selection is totally screwed up and crashes (I think in sourceList it draws the selection using an outside process in Quartz server).
Steps to reproduce:
1) use a NSTabviewcontroller,
2) place a NSOutlineview in source-list mode in each tab.
3) select in tab-1, change to tab-2, and try to select something.
Selection is now no longer visible at all. If you go back to tab-1, also the selection there is non-functional.

If you make another window active, and then make your app active again, then the selection is drawn again.
All of this works fine in High Sierra, but fails in all Mojave betas.

Comment: Still not fixed in beta 5.

Comment: at least beta 5 fixed my case... we faced diff problem probably

Comment: Fixed in beta 6!